# Get all list elements between two dates in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

the python list is as below

['2020-06-26 15:23:11', '2020-06-26 15:20:31', '2020-06-26 08:24:13', '2020-06-25 18:32:17', '2020-06-25 18:19:24', '2020-06-25 18:12:36', '2020-06-25 17:01:28']

I need to get the elements between two date element.

python code is like this:

```
startdate = '2020-06-25 18:19:24'
enddate = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    
event = ['2020-06-26 15:23:11', '2020-06-26 15:20:31', '2020-06-26 08:24:13', '2020-06-25 18:32:17', '2020-06-25 18:19:24', '2020-06-25 18:12:36', '2020-06-25 17:01:28']

initime = []

for event>startdate and event<=endate:
    intime.append(format(event))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select a chunk of list between two values in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630340/how-to-select-a-chunk-of-list-between-two-values-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  A couple things...

- you need to make everything into a datetime object in order to compare properly
- you can use list comprehensions to do most of the work here
- the below example could be made more efficient if your list of inputs is sorted, but it won't make a difference unless your list is just huge.

---

```
from datetime import datetime

# step 1:  get both of your cutoffs into datetime objects
startdate_str = '2020-06-25 18:19:24'
start_date = datetime.strptime(startdate_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
end_date = datetime.now()
    
event = ['2020-06-26 15:23:11', '2020-06-26 15:20:31', '2020-06-26 08:24:13', '2020-06-25 18:32:17', '2020-06-25 18:19:24', '2020-06-25 18:12:36', '2020-06-25 17:01:28']

# step 2:  Convert the strings in your list to datetime elements
event_dt = [datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for t in event]

# Step 3:  use another list comprehension to test each element
in_window = [dt for dt in event_dt if start_date <= dt and dt <= end_date]

for dt in in_window:
    print(dt)
```

Yields:

```
2020-06-26 08:24:13
2020-06-25 18:32:17
2020-06-25 18:19:24
[Finished in 0.1s]
```